# How can I change the parent of an epic in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

We are using GitLab internally in my company, but I'm pretty new to this tool.  We are only a few sprints into a new project, but have started arranging the backlog into epics and issues.  I would now like to re-organize some of the epics and at least one needs to be a child of another epic.  Both the (potential) child epic and the (potential) parent epic have issues of their own. I can create a new epic as a child, but want to just change an existing one.

In the Epic  view, on the right hand side menu, there is an entry that says "Ancestors" but it isn't editable. Is there a different way to re-organize the epics into a hierarchy?

Comment: When you follow the [docu for epics on gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/epics/) you can see that relationship between epics is a `ultimate` feature. Are you on a free plan? You can also use the Qucick-Actions `/parent_epic`, quickactions are comments which are starting with `/` [see here](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/quick_actions)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. In my case I needed to remove the epic parent. You can change or remove the parent epic with quick actions. In particular `/parent_epic` allows you to change the parent epic and `/remove_parent_epic` will remove your parent epic.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/quick_actions.html#issues-merge-requests-and-epics

EDIT: I just noticed @KargWare's comment also mentions quick actions, so looks like he originally answered this already.