# How can a GitLab issue be promoted to an epic programmatically?

Tags: python-3.x, gitlab, python-gitlab

I am supporting a set of teams that have a large number of issues that need to be promoted to epics.  I am working on a Python 3 script to do this using python-gitlab v3.14.0.  However, i do not see a function offered for promoting an issue.  (I do see capabilities for promoting labels and milestones.)

How can i promote issues via my python script and the GitLab Premium API?

The following question was similar but not quite what i am looking for.
[How can I change the parent of an epic in GitLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74881607/how-can-i-change-the-parent-of-an-epic-in-gitlab)

Comment: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/issues.html#promote-an-issue-to-an-epic

Comment: @luk2302 -- i was hoping to not have to weight my script down with requests to do curl commands, but if that is the only option ...

Comment: What? Maybe the lib you use does simply support that, otherwise it is a simple `requests` call, not slowing down anything.